# Multiple public IPs routed via Cisco ASA to Proxmox VMs

Tags: cisco, kvm-virtualization, cisco-asa, proxmox, ip-routing

I have a network with IP 199.221.2.136 (/29). I would like the Cisco ASA5505 [1] to work on .137 as router and use two public IPs (.138 and .139) on two VMs on a Proxmox server. Not sure how to route those public IPs to VMs via Cisco and Proxmox.

One VM will be transfered from OVH to our own hardware, the second will be brand new (if that changes anything).

Later (but not important right now), with two other public IPs, I would like to use them with different VMs on other Proxmox server.

[1] also have Cisco C3825, if this would be better to do the job

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

A. Trunk a VLAN for your public IP range straight to the Proxmox hosts which will allow you to connect a vNIC on your VM's directly to the public network with the IP's you have.

B. Use SNAT on your ASA (If the license supports it) to 1:1 map your public addresses to the LAN addresses of your VM's.